# Center a Dialog relative to CView

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to center a `CMyDialog` relative to `CView`.

I do this inside `CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()` with `CenterWindow(m_pParentWnd);`
But it does not work as expected, wrong position. (too much down
too much right)

I have to correct the original `CenterWindow(CWnd* pAlternateOwner)` a little as follow:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Centering dialog support (works for any non-child window)

//void CWnd::CenterWindow(CWnd* pAlternateOwner)
void CMyDlg::CenterWindow(CWnd* pAlternateOwner)
{
  ..
  ..
  // find dialog's upper left based on rcCenter
  //int xLeft = (rcCenter.left + rcCenter.right) / 2 - rcDlg.Width() / 2;  // wrong
  //int yTop = (rcCenter.top + rcCenter.bottom) / 2 - rcDlg.Height() / 2;   // wrong 

  int   xLeft = (rcCenter.right - rcCenter.left) / 2 - rcDlg.Width() / 2;   // right
  int   yTop = (rcCenter.bottom - rcCenter.top) / 2 - rcDlg.Height() / 2;   // right 
  ..
  ..
}
```

Is the MFC calculation wrong or are there some prerequisites that I am missed?

Comment: Have you looked at this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678/A-Better-CenterWindow-Function

Comment: My link basically does what you are doing actually. :)

Comment: No! That is the same code for calculating xLeft and yTop as the original CWnd::CenterWindow(). That center to the MainWnd(Dlg), but not to a CView window.

Comment: True. But the principle is there. You use whatever object you like as the parent.

Comment: Look here: https://weseetips.wordpress.com/tag/getactiveview/ You could get the active view and centre to that.

Comment: Beside that, the article on codeproject you mentioned is meaningless, Here You don't need to write your own CenterWindow(). You need only pass a this pointer to CSubDialog dlg (this), and the original CWnd::CenterWindow(m_pParentWnd) works.

Comment: [Window Coordinate System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/window-coordinate-system).